# Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at https://example.com

Tags: javascript, server-sent-events

I have a webserver and I want to implement server-event Source via:
EventSource("API.php")
but I ran into error on random requests!
For example After 120 Requests I get the error or the other time after 31 requests!
what is the problem and how to solve that?

Site CODE:

```
<!DocType 'html'>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
  // Yes! Server-sent events support!
  // Some code.....
var source = new EventSource("Example.php");
source.onmessage = function(event) {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
}; 


} else {
  alert("Use FireFox to Load This Page! Your Browser is not supported...")
} 


</script>

</body>
<footer></footer>
</html>
```

[image: sample image]

Comment: You can't do anything about this. Error code is _521 Web Server Is Down_

Comment: FYI - the doctype tag should be `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: As stated by @Justinas It looks like you should be looking at the HTTP 521 status code and figure out what's causing that. IIRC 521 is a non-standard error code that Cloudflare use.

Answer (score 1):

This ("521") is apparently a cloudflare-specific error. So your problem is server-side, not with your JavaScript.

There are plenty of suggestions online; I suggest your search terms should be "cloudflare 521". Or "cloudflare server sent events". Don't search for "cloudflare SSE" as that abbreviation has multiple meanings in that context.

It seems what people normally do is create a rule to not use Cloudflare for your SSE endpoints.